# Alterar um valor de uma key em um dicionario Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso pegar a posição de um dos values da key `'Codigo'`, por exemplo `321`, e nessa mesma posição alterar o valor da key `'Status aluguel'` para `'S'`. Como posso fazer isso?

```
Imoveis_Cadastrados = {
  'Codigo': [123, 321],
  'CPF_PROP': [],
  'Tipo': [],
  'Endereço': [],
  'Valor_Aluguel': [],
  'Status_Aluguel': ['N', 'N']
}
```

O objetivo é que fique assim:

```
Imoveis_Cadastrados = {
  'Codigo': [123, 321],
  'CPF_PROP': [],
  'Tipo': [],
  'Endereço': [],
  'Valor_Aluguel': [],
  'Status_Aluguel': ['N', 'S']
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa da chave do `'Código'` para acessar os valores da chave `'Status_Aluguel'`. Você utiliza as chaves para você acessar os valores diretamente. Por exemplo:

```
Imoveis_Cadastrados['Status_Aluguel'] = ['N', 'S']
```

Agora vamos supor que você tenha uma lista grande dentro de cada chave do dicionário. Nesse caso, uma opção então é utilizar o método `index()` para encontrar a posição correspondente ao valor desejado (no caso, `321`) na lista de `'Código'`. Em seguida, você utiliza esse mesmo valor como input para alterar a mesma posição na lista de `'Status_Aluguel'`:

```
indice = Imoveis_Cadastrados['Codigo'].index(321)
Imoveis_Cadastrados['Status_Aluguel'][indice] = 'S'
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu dicionário está do "avesso".

O correto não é usar um dicionário de forma que os valores sejam *listas* e cada posição nas listas, em todos os valores no dicionário, corresponda a um registro (isso é: o conjunto de informações referentes a um objeto).

O correto é ter uma lista, onde cada elemento da lista é um dicionário, e aí sim, todas as informações do seu registro vem juntas.

No caso, você teria algo como:

```py
imoveis_cadastrados = [
{'Codigo': 123 'CPF_PROP': None, 'Tipo': None, 'Endereço': None, 'Valor_Aluguel': None, 'Status_Aluguel': 'N'},
 {'Codigo': 321, 'CPF_PROP': None, 'Tipo': None, 'Endereço': None, 'Valor_Aluguel': None, 'Status_Aluguel': 'N'}
]
```

aí, pronto.

Pode fazer uma busca linear fazendo algo assim:

```py
imovel = [im for im in imoveis_cadastrados if im["código"] == 321]
imovel["Status_Aluguel"] = "S"
```

Se quiser sempre localizar pelo código, pode usar a estrutura de fora como um dicionário, em que a chave é sempre o código - aí nao precisa da chave "Código" nos dicionários interiores:

```py
imoveis_cadastrados = {123: {'CPF_PROP': None, 'Tipo': None, 'Endereço': None, 'Valor_Aluguel': None, 'Status_Aluguel': 'N'},
 321: {'CPF_PROP': None, 'Tipo': None, 'Endereço': None, 'Valor_Aluguel': None, 'Status_Aluguel': 'N'}}
```

E pra udar o status de um imóvel, dado o código:

```
imoveis_cadastrados[321]["Status_Aluguel"] = "S"
```

Se precisar localizar móveis por critérios diferentes do código, tipo "liste todos os imóveis do CPF xxxx", aí o melhor é usar uma estrutura em SQL em vez de dicionários.

O Python vem com o banco sqlite embutido, que pode armazenar os dados em memória, o que teria o comportamento equivalente a um dicionário, mas também pode armazenar os valores em um arquivo, que será mantido sincronizado. Se o seu probelma for parte de um programa real que você está fazendo, guardar os seus dados em um arquivo é algo que você vai querer fazer de qualquer forma.

E a vantagem de usar SQL nesse caso é menos ser qualquer caritério de eficiência - a não ser que você vá ter um cadastro com dezenas de milhares de imóveis, e sim, por que a linguagem SQL permite expressar essas buscas de forma natural. (Embora a recomendação para projetos reais seja, dar outro passo e usar um "wrapper" para o SQL, e usar tudo como classes de Python, com a ajuda de um ORM como o SQLAlchemy ou o framework Django)

Comment: outra dica, não relacionada com o seu problema - uma questão de estilo, mas que é bem prática: não use nomes misturando maiúsculas e minúsculas _E_ underscores - so vão te dar trabalho pra digitar, e são difíceis de ler - tudo em minúsculas fica mais agradável de ler - e, na hora de exibir na interface do usuário, há funções como o método `.title` das strings que podem transformar as iniciais em maiúsculas se você achar interessante.